# Vue watch for two variable mutually linked on change leads to infinite loop

Tags: vue.js, infinite-loop

I have a vue app like

```
var VueAppExport = new Vue({
    el: '#nav_section_downloads',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'], //to avoid conflict with django template
    data: {
        xport: {width: 1000, height: 1000, lock: true}
    },
    watch: {
        'xport.width' : {
            handler: function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (this.xport.lock){
                    this.xport.height = parseInt(this.xport.height) + parseInt(newValue) - parseInt(oldValue);
                }
            },
        },
        'xport.height' : {
            handler: function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (this.xport.lock){
                    this.xport.width = parseInt(this.xport.width) + parseInt(newValue) - parseInt(oldValue);
                }
            },
        },        
    },

})
```

I want the scenario where if width or height value changes then commensurately height/width value change when lock is true.

Problem with my code is infinite looping. watching changes in width and in case of change changing height while at the same time watching height and then changing width is feeding each other infinitely.

I tried to set value by compute method but in compute setter old value is not available.

Is there any way out to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to [watch](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) whole object `xport` like:

```
watch: {
  xport: {
    handler(val, oldVal){
    // do stuff
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Comment: In your suggested method, val and oldVal will be same equal to new value i.e val.